# Configure mongoose to use x509 client certificate to connect to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl, mongoose, x509certificate

I'm trying to configure mongoose to connect to my MongoDB 3.0 server, all on localhost.

My server conf file is as follows:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
       path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"
       logAppend: true
storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true
processManagement:
   fork: true
net:
   port: 27017
   ssl: 
     mode: requireSSL

     #These are generated using my own local CA 
     PEMKeyFile: "/etc/ssl/mongoServer.pem"
     CAFile: "/etc/ssl/rootCA.pem"

setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
   authenticationMechanisms: MONGODB-X509
```

The server runs, and I can connect to is using the mongo shell, with the following command:

```
mongo -ssl --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/mongoServer.pem --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongoClient.pem
```

(Oddly, for some reason, if I use rootCA.pem for --sslCAFile, rather than mongoServer.pem, it does not connect. But that's another question...)

Great!

Now, I'm trying to set up a mongoose client to connect to the same server. Here are the configuration options I'm using.

```
var dbConnectString = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testDb";

var options = {
    server: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1
        }
    }
};

options.server.ssl = true;
options.server.sslCert = fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/mongoClient.pem");
options.server.sslKey = fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/mongoClient.pem");     
options.server.sslCA = fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/mongoServer.pem");   
options.server.sslValidate = false;

mongoose.connect(dbConnectString, options);
```

This does not work. When I test it, I get "Error: connection closed".

I've also tried using the individual key and crt files (which were concatenated to make the pem files), and they wouldn't connect either.

I've read the documentation in all these places:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/connecting/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

And I believe I am doing this correctly. However, I'm probably not, because it's not working. Corrections, suggestions or solutions are apprecated. Thanks!

Comment: What's in your mongodb logs when you try and connect?

Comment: Ever figure out what was wrong?

Comment: Alas, no, and then I moved on to other things. I think, possibly, that the issue might be that version of mongoose had a bug preventing ssl connections; a bug fixed in a later version. But that is conjecture.